# How do I get the selected text from SelectionContainer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to get the selected text from the `Text` component. I tried using the `SelectionContainer`, but it does not have an `onSelectionChange` callback or something similar.

Edit: I have to highlight the text the user selected

Edit 2: I have asked in the issue tracker, and it's not possible to do that yet. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195441731

Answer (score 1):

If you are not forced to use Text() ...
An easy way is to use Composable TextField() and change readOnly to true
because you need a TextFieldValue argument to get selected text

for example if i want that selected text in custom TextField , my code will be look like this:

```
@Composable fun TextWithSelectedText( 
    text:String = "This is a plain text",
    selectedText:MutableState<String>){
    var textInput by remember{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text))}
    TextField(
        value = textInput,
        onValueChange = { newValue ->
            textInput = newValue
            selectedText.value = textInput.getSelectedText().text
        } ,
        readOnly =  true ,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.White , // your background color
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent ,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another method to get text, but it is not perfect.

That is why this method is not perfect.

[image: That is why this method is not perfect]

First, copy text to the clipboard, then get text from it. This needs you to custom `TextToolbar`.

Here is an example, you can find it all from [GitHub](https://github.com/ZTFtrue/MonsterMusic/blob/9bed317a4c8f2bad85df1675cc8a1e77cfd74c22/app/src/main/java/com/ztftrue/music/ui/play/LyricsView.kt#L293)

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalTextToolbar provides CustomTextToolbar(
                LocalView.current,
                musicViewModel.dictionaryAppList,
                LocalFocusManager.current,
                LocalClipboardManager.current
            ),
        ){

 SelectionContainer(){}

}
```

CustomTextToolbar

```
// CustomTextToolbar
 override fun showMenu(
        rect: Rect,
        onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)?

// Before 1.2.0 ActionCallback has to be defined like this:
// typealias ActionCallback = () -> Unit
//
//  onCopyRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onPasteRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onCutRequested: ActionCallback?,
//  onSelectAllRequested: ActionCallback?
    ) {
       textActionModeCallback.onProcessAppItemClick = {
            onCopyRequested?.invoke()
            val t = clipboardManager.getText()
           // make clipboard space
           // clipboardManager.setText(buildAnnotatedString { append("")})
             
 

        }
}
```